# Two NICs with DHCP, use one as fallback

Tags: debian, wifi, iproute

The scenario is as follows: Linux box, running Debian, having two NICs (a broadband connection as well as a Wifi connection), both with DHCP and no information about the networks known in advance and subject to change over time. We want to use the wifi connection as default but automatically fallback to the broadband connection if the wifi connection fails for whatever reason. Additionally, once the wifi connection starts working again, we want to automatically go back to the wifi connection.

Any idea how to set this up? I'm imaging to do this via ip routes, but the probing of the wifi connection should be fairly general like a ping to a specific server (the reason the check should be something like a ping is that the wifi connection might still be present, but the wifi itself is not connected to the internet anymore).

Comment: Assuming WPA/WPA2 and wpasupplicant: Hook into the connected/disconnected actions via `wpa_action` and `ifup`/`ifdown`, set/remove default route for broadband. Haven't tried this myself, so I can't give details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it via the following background script:

```
#!/bin/sh
PRIMARY=wlan0
SECONDARY=eth1
SLEEP=60
PING=8.8.8.8
CONDITION="100% packet loss"


while :
do
    echo Init
    ifmetric $PRIMARY 100
    ifmetric $SECONDARY 200
    if [ "`ip route | grep default | grep $PRIMARY`" = "" ];
    then
        ip route add default via `ip route show | grep $PRIMARY | grep "scope link" | sed 's/\(.*\)0\/.*/\1/'`1 dev $PRIMARY
    fi
    if [ "`ip route | grep default | grep $SECONDARY`" = "" ];
    then
        ip route add default via `ip route show | grep $SECONDARY | grep "scope link" | sed 's/\(.*\)0\/.*/\1/'`1 dev $SECONDARY
    fi
    ifmetric $PRIMARY 100
    ifmetric $SECONDARY 200
    echo Primary
    while [ "`ping -I $PRIMARY -c 10 -w 20 $PING | grep \"$CONDITION\"`" = "" ];
    do
        sleep $SLEEP
    done
    echo Secondary
    ifmetric $SECONDARY 50
    while [ -n "`ping -I $PRIMARY -c 10 -w 20 $PING | grep \"$CONDITION\"`" ];
    do
        ifdown $PRIMARY
        sleep $SLEEP
        ifup $PRIMARY
        sleep $SLEEP
    done
done
```